# Periods before links are unreliable... alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

When referring to a different page on my website, I have to use a link somewhat like this:
`"./index"`

I believe the period sends the link one directory up, but I may be wrong. The problem is that I have a file in one directory that I include in multiple pages, and it references a file. But I don't want to have to have a check to see where it's being run from to determine the number of periods necessary.

What I would like to be able to do is `"<starting directory>/page"`. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the code you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: no you don't, and yes, you're wrong. `.` means current dir, `..` means parent dir. For a relative link in the same dir, you can just point to `href="theotherpage.html"`.

Comment: . = current directory / .. = level up

Comment: The code isn't necessary, I just need another way to go to the root directory. I can narrate the example more tho. 
file1's directory is public_html/file1.php
file2's directory is public_html/extras/file2.php
file3's directory is public_html/special/file3.php
file4's directory is public_html/special/file4.php

If file3 includes file4 for a function, and file3 is a small container which is included on multiple pages, then without doing a test to see where file3 is being included from (file1 or 2), is there a way to just go to the starting directory so that file4 is always loaded?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you! Parent just means one level up, right? What happens when I do like "............/index"? Would that go to the top or would it screw up and stop loading things?

Comment: parent is one level up, to go up multiple levels, you use `../` multiple times. To go up three levels, `../../../yourFile3levelsUp.html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` is the current directory and `..` is the parent.  `./index.html` is the same as `index.html` -- this file in the current directory relative to the directory of the current page.  For example if you were on `/some/path/other.html`, a link to `./index.html` would go to `/some/path/index.html`.

It is generally a good idea to use absolute paths for URLs and assets (such as stylesheets / javascript files) as this allows you to reference them consistently.  That is, your links should be `/path/to/index.html`.  Using relative paths does have the advantage of consistency when referring to files in the same directory and moving that directory, but I think this is less advantageous when compared to moving files between directories.  The absolute path to files that were not moved does not need to change.

Answer (score 1):

`/path/from/root/to/target.ext` - using a slash at the start makes the link relative to your domain.